# Issue with Hibernate 4.3.5 upgrade

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm really new to Hibernate and currently upgrading Hibernate from 4.1.9 to 4.3.5. Here is the list of existing hibernate jars:

> `antlr-2.7.7.jar,hibenate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar ,hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar ,hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar ,javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar ,jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar,jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar`

I've replaced these jars with the latest Hibernate jars. Here is the list:

> `antlr-2.7.7.jar,hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar,hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar,hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar,javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar,jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar,jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar`

After replacing the jars I get a compilation error, and I've changed the below code to fix the issue:

```
/* Existing code */
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry =
   new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
   .applySettings(config.getProperties())
   .buildServiceRegistry();

/* Modified code */
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry =
   new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
   .applySettings(config.getProperties())
   .build();
```

Issue: As I run my application one of the operations is getting an empty `HashSet`, whereas with the earlier version of the Hibernate jars it was getting a `PersistentSet`.
I'm checking if the object is empty or not. With the `PersistentSet` it clears the check, but with the `HashSet` it fails the check for the same data.

Is there anything else I need to do this upgrade? Is there anything which I need to change to handle this kind of situation while doing this upgrade?

The application is using Hibernate mapping. Here is the mapping for the set I was talking about above:

```
<set name="Code" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" where="created_date=(select max(c.created_date) from dma_step_code c where c.step_id=step_id)">
   <key column="step_id"/>
   <one-to-many class="com.hp.dma.data.action.SOPActionCode" />
</set>
```